# How to free memory allocated by pcre2_get_ovector_pointer method?

Tags: c, pcre

How to properly free\release memory allocated by pcre2_get_ovector_pointer method of pcre2 library?

For example:

```
PCRE2_SIZE *ovector;
ovector = pcre2_get_ovector_pointer(match_data);
```

So, how to release the **ovector** pointer?

Comment: What does the library/call documentation say?

Comment: you should consult the documentation of that library. Usually a library takes care of freeing ressources with special functions if you don't allocate them yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't. `ovector` points to data within `match_data`.

You need to free `match_data` using.

```
pcre2_match_data_free(match_data);
```

[example](http://homeunix.nl/manual/pcre2/html/pcre2demo.html)

Comment: Yes, I looked at the source code of the library, this is right, thank you!